# Multiprotocol auth with one SSO server

Tags: oauth-2.0, saml, cas

Can I use one SSO server (Apereo CAS) for authentication web apps with different protocols (e.g. app 1 uses SAML, app2 uses oAuth2.0)?

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Comment: I want run one instance of SSO server and connect to them 2 web apps, one with SAML and second with oAuth2.0. Is it possible to configure with Apereo software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Some additional notes:
https://apereo.github.io/2018/02/26/cas-delegation-protocols/

Comment: Thanks, this is what I’m looking for